# Binding to Auto-value in XAML

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I guess the auto-value is set after parsed by the binding.

Binding code:

```
Width="{Binding Capacity, Converter={StaticResource CapacityConverter}, ElementName=LayoutPath}" 
Height="{Binding Capacity, Converter={StaticResource CapacityConverter}, ElementName=LayoutPath}"
```

Source:

```
<LayoutPath 
    x:Name="LayoutPath" 
    SourceElement="{Binding ElementName=ellipse}" 
    FillBehavior="NoOverlap" 
    Orientation="OrientToPath" 
    Capacity="auto" 
    Padding="34" 
    Distribution="Even"/>
```

It works if I set capacity to a fixed value, but not when it auto-calculates based on total nodes in xml.

Any solution?

-

Comment: Please the the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the formatting of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding to `ActualCapacity` instead.

Comment: Well, this returns value = 0: 
      `Width="{Binding ActualCapacity, Converter={StaticResource CapacityConverter}, ElementName=LayoutPath}"`

Comment: The problem is that the property provides no updates, when the binding is first queried the control is not sufficiently loaded and you get 0 but when the capacity is calculated you are not notified.

Comment: Ok, thanks! :)
So what should I do next, create my own notifier onCalculated? Or maybe set a timeout for the calculation in someway?

Comment: I think getting actual notifications to work might not be trivial, the class does not offer suitable events to hook into and it is sealed. But the `PathListBox.Loaded` event seems quite suitable, you can either update the bindings or just do an assignment there since the binding is somewhat pointless without updates.

Comment: Ok, so its not possible to do this in pure xaml? Thanks again!

Comment: Well, the Loaded event is a RoutedEvent so you could use an EventTrigger and try to set the properties with single-frame animations, in theory you can do pretty much anything in XAML, question is if it makes sense and if it is worth it.

Comment: Perfect! :)
Working code:
`ellipse.SetValue(HeightProperty, LayoutPath.ActualCapacity); `
`ellipse.SetValue(WidthProperty, LayoutPath.ActualCapacity); `
        }`